# Unauthorized Access when posting status to Twitter using RestSharp and oAuth1.0a

Tags: c#, rest, twitter, restsharp

EDIT: My original issue was related a firewall issue, now my issue is in my authorization. With both methods below I receive and "Unauthorized" response.

I'm trying to create a method that will allow me to post a status update to twitter. I'm trying to use in my application so that I can know when certain events are taking place throughout the day without having to monitor the logs, so I thought this would be a cool way to push notifications out. Only other option I could think of is email notifications but wanted to try something different (open to any other ideas of push notifications)

I've been struggling the majority of the day to try and get this code to work. Most of the examples and questions about this I've been reviewing are quite old. Below is the code I'm running.

The Response.StatusCode = 0 and the Response.Content is blank, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
No exception is thrown, so the response must be getting executed, but does not return anything.

I've followed the guide here on creating the signature.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

Any feedback would be welcome, I wondering if there is anything obvious that I'm doing wrong.

Once I have the solution to this I'm hoping to share it out, once its cleaned up with much more comments.

**Using the Code Below**

```
Tweet t = new Tweet();
t.TestTweet();
```

**Additional NameSpaces**

```
using RestSharp;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

**Class**

```
class Tweet
    {
        private string myFirstMessage = "First Message Using RestSharp";
        private const string baseTwitterURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

        //Keys in Alphabetical Order
        private string oauth_consumer_key = GlobalVariables.ConsumerKey;
        private string oauth_nonce = "abcd";
        private string oauth_signature;
        private string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        private string oauth_timestamp;
        private string oauth_token = GlobalVariables.Token;
        private string oauth_version = "1.0";


        private string ConsumerKeySecret = GlobalVariables.ConsumerKeySecret;
        private string AccessTokenSecret = GlobalVariables.AccessTokenSecret;

        public Tweet()
        {

            DateTime epochUtc = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var timestamp = (int)((DateTime.UtcNow - epochUtc).TotalSeconds);

            oauth_timestamp = timestamp.ToString();
        }

        public void TestTweet()
        {
            string fullURL = baseTwitterURL + Uri.EscapeDataString(myFirstMessage);

            var client = new RestClient(fullURL);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            string parameterString = GenerateParameterString(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, oauth_version);
            string signatureBaseString = GenerateSignatureBaseString(parameterString);
            string signingKey = GenerateSigningKey();

            HMACSHA1 mySignature = new HMACSHA1();

            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(mySignature.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", signatureBaseString, signingKey))));

            request.AddHeader("authorization", "OAuth");

            request.AddParameter("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
            request.AddParameter("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
            request.AddParameter("oauth_signature", oauth_signature);
            request.AddParameter("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
            request.AddParameter("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
            request.AddParameter("oauth_token", oauth_token);
            request.AddParameter("oauth_version", oauth_version);

            string requestString = string.Join(",", request.Parameters.ToList());

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attemping to send response" + "\n");
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Ex.Message: " + Ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Ex.ToString: " + Ex.ToString());
            }

        }

        public string GenerateParameterString(
            string oauth_consumer_key,
            string oauth_nonce,
            string oauth_signature_method,
            string oauth_timestamp,
            string oauth_token,
            string oauth_version)
        {
            StringBuilder parameterString = new StringBuilder();

            parameterString.Append("include_entities=true&");
            parameterString.Append("oauth_consumer_key=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key) + "&");
            parameterString.Append("oauth_nonce=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce) + "&");
            parameterString.Append("oauth_signature_method=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method) + "&");
            parameterString.Append("oauth_timestamp=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp) + "&");
            parameterString.Append("oauth_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token) + "&");
            parameterString.Append("oauth_version=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version) + "&");
            parameterString.Append("status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(myFirstMessage));


            return parameterString.ToString();
        }

        public string GenerateSignatureBaseString(string parameterString)
        {
            StringBuilder SignatureBaseString = new StringBuilder();

            SignatureBaseString.Append("POST&");
            SignatureBaseString.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(baseTwitterURL));
            SignatureBaseString.Append("&");
            SignatureBaseString.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(parameterString));

            return SignatureBaseString.ToString();
        }

        public string GenerateSigningKey()
        {
            StringBuilder SigningKey = new StringBuilder();

            SigningKey.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(ConsumerKeySecret));
            SigningKey.Append("&");
            SigningKey.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(AccessTokenSecret));

            return SigningKey.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**Edited: RestSharp OAuth1Authenticator Method**

```
public void TestTweetWithAuthenticator()
{
    string fullURL = baseTwitterURL;
    var client = new RestClient(fullURL)

    {
        Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(oauth_consumer_key, ConsumerKeySecret, oauth_token, AccessTokenSecret)
    };
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    request.AddParameter("status", Uri.EscapeDataString(myFirstMessage));

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attemping to send response" + "\n");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the OAuth1 authenticator that does things for you?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev 
I tried updating my method to the second version of the code (updated my original post to include this below by original method) and get the same result. I had to change the URL to just the baseURL for this method.

Comment: I see. OAuth1 is not easy, I wouldn't even go there since Twitter supports OAuth2 bearer token anyway. But if you prefer OAuth1, you might be willing to make a request in Postman or curl and check it out in Fiddler. Then, compare it with the request made by RestSharp. If you can clearly see differences, please open an issue in RestSharp repository so we can have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot post using bearer token, so that would not work in this case. I've had success using the OAuth DotNetCore library. https://github.com/andypiper/TwitterDotNetCore/tree/master